# Determine if a regex is just a literal match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Using the .NET Regex class is there an easy way to check whether a regex is a literal match with no special characters (save for escaped special characters)?

Looking for something like this

```
var literalRegex = new Regex(@"\(foo\)");
var fancyRegex = new Regex("foo.*");
Console.WriteLine(IsPlainLiteral(literalRegex)); // True
Console.WriteLine(IsPlainLiteral(fancyRegex)); // False
```

Comment: @SgtRock: How is that supposed to help? The OP is looking for a way to determine in C# source code whether any given regex string uses any "fancy" regex functions or whether it is just a 1:1 (save for escapes) string match.

Comment: `A literal match` as opposed to one with no special characters? Just test the regex _string_ for unescaped metacharacters. You would have to find the root of the escapes to do that. Something like `@"(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*[.^$|*?+(){}\[\]]"` If it matches it has metachars.

Comment: Looks like now you have 4 problems :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this pattern that matches all "literal patterns" *(* understand well-formed patterns where all characters are literals or escaped special characters or ignored backslashes)*

in a verbatim string:

```
\A
[^[\\|{.?*+^$()]*    # characters that aren't one of the twelve special characters
(?>
    (?: # exceptions:
        # - the opening curly bracket that is not the start of a quantifier
        {+ (?! [0-9]+ (?:,[0-9]*)? } ) 
      |
        # - the backslash if it escapes a character:
            # - that is one of the twelve special characters
            # - or produces an ignored escape sequence
        \\ [^\p{L}\p{N}]
    )
    [^[\\|{.?*+^$()]*
)*
\z
```

Note: this pattern is designed for the .net syntax.

Note2: for patterns with the `IgnorePatternWhitespace` option, you must exclude spaces and `#` from the character class to do the same, so: `[^[\\|{.?*+^$()#\s]`

Answer (score 0):

An easy **correct** way? I don't think there exists one.

However, if you are not scared of a little bit reflection hacking, it should be quite easy. Namely, once Regex object has been initialized, you have access to abstract syntax tree called RegexTree.

All you need to do is just answer this question:

does the tree only have 1 node and is the node only literal node?

One other option is to write your own regex parser that follows the syntax of C# regex, and build the AST yourself.

Comment: Not entirely sure though of the use case here, but if it's something that people would like, it's always possible to create a feature request in .NET branch at github. They wouldn't probably have anything against creating simple extension method for this case, if it's helpful for people.

Comment: Highly doubtful they'd accept such a feature, given the very narrow use cases. Each feature has to be of lasting value and will basically have to be supported forever.